# Is there a way to suspend the system?

Tags: standby, sleep

I have Android tablet, whenever I lock the device it goes to sleep, but it is actually operating mode, when programs can run, notify me, etc.

I am looking for suspend mode, just as with regular computer, when program do not run in suspend mode.

Comment: Android devices are designed to be always on. There is no suspend mode, you can only power it off or leave it running. When keep it running you can enable all battery savings like disable all wireless interfaces).

Comment: Some history: [Do Android 3.0 tablets have standby/hibernate mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9003/44325) (asked about Android 3.0 specifically, but mostly true until now in 2022). Possibly related/some alternative suggestion: [How to make an Android smartphone actually go to sleep?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221773/44325). For notification, [the Do Not Disturb mode](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9069335) might also help.

Comment: [Suspend to RAM](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Android+suspend+to+RAM) requires specific support at hardware, bootloader, Linux kernel and userspace level. All or some of these are not available on Android devices.